# Django models: which field to use for position/order of an object

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

My project is a basic scrum board with a model `Column`, of which there can be unlimited instances. Each column is displayed side by side, and I want the order of the columns to be customizable. My thought was to use an `IntegerField` to determine numerical position, but I'm struggling with how to set the `max_value` equal to the total number of columns since it varies by board.

Here's how I set it up:

```
class Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True,min_value=1, max_value=???)
```

My problem was what to use as the max_value. I tried solving it by doing this:

```
class Column(models.Model):
    
    max_value = Column.objects.get(board=board).count()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True,min_value=1, max_value=max_value)
```

I know this obviously won't work. Could I somehow use `class Meta` to set constraints instead, or what would be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could redefine `save()` method.

```
class Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True, min_value=1)
    
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        position_max_value = type(self).objects.get(board=self.board).count()
        if self.position > position_max_value:
            raise ValueError(...)
        super().save(**kwargs)
```